# What's the most efficient way to store XUIDs on SQL?

Tags: mysql, xbox-live

The official Xbox Auth documentation refers to XUID as an unsigned int64, and therefore, I expected the SQL equivalent, BIGINT, to be the most efficient way to store it on a MySQL database.

However, I found out that many programmers are storing XUIDs on their databases as VARCHAR(20), after some research these are the key differences I found between these data types:

1. VARCHAR(20) uses **up to 21 bytes** (depending on the length of the text)
2. BIGINT **always uses 8 bytes**, independently of the length of the text.

This is how this question came to my mind, what is the most efficient way to store XUIDs on SQL?

Comment: How are you using it in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a XUID is a 64-bit unsigned integer, then it can have values from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. So `VARCHAR(10)` will not be large enough; you would need to use `VARCHAR(20)`.

It should be slightly more efficient (and use a little less database disk space) to store it as a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (always [eight bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)) than `VARCHAR(20)` (up to 21 bytes depending on the magnitude of the number being stored, assuming a one-byte-per-digit character set for the column).